# How do I access the window object from within Elm?

Tags: elm

Specifically, I am trying to initialize Elm with an already defined parameter. Something like:

```
initialModel =
    { me = window.user
    , todos = window.todos
    }
```

All I can find is how to get window dimensions using signals, but I'm on Elm 0.18 and it seems slightly outdated.

Edit: Just to be clear, the above code wouldn't work. Whatever was attached to the `window` object would have to be JS, so it'd have to go through a decoder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use [`programWithFlags`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Platform#programWithFlags) to pass initial values from javascript. The "flags" you pass from javascript should have equivalent record type if you want to use Elm's automatic type conversion:

Let's say your `me` is just a string, but your `todos` is a list of boolean flags and a label. Your `Flags` type could look like this:

```elm
type alias Todo =
    { done : Bool, label : String }

type alias Flags =
    { me : String, todos : List Todo }
```

Your `init` function would need to handle the flags value appropriately. Here is an example of just assigning the fields to Model fields of the same name:

```elm
type alias Model =
    { me : String, todos : List Todo }

main : Program Flags Model Msg
main =
    Html.programWithFlags
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = \_ -> Sub.none
        }

init : Flags -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init flags =
    { me = flags.me, todos = flags.todos } ! []
```

Your javascript will need to be updated to pass in the flags. You do that by passing a json object as the first parameter to fullscreen or embed:

```js
var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen({
  "me": "John Doe",
  "todos": [
    { done: true, label: "Do this thing" },
    { done: false, label: "And this thing" }
  ]
});
```

Here is a [working example on ellie-app.com](https://ellie-app.com/3cBcPqGstZYa1/0)

If Elm's automatic json-to-mapping conversion isn't strong enough for your decoding, you could instead use the [`Json.Decode.Value`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#Value) type as your flag, then [`Json.Decode.decodeValue`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/5.1.1/Json-Decode#decodeValue) using your customer decoder. [Here is an example on ellie-app.com of using a custom decoder](https://ellie-app.com/3cBpzzwb6QMa1/0).

Comment: This is brilliant. Thank you so much.